# Why JSON response is null while using Repository class instead of direct ApiProvider class in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to parse json from an Api. Here is my ApiProvider class :

```
class ArticleApiProvider {

  String articleUrl = "api";
  List<Article> articleList = [];

  Future<List<Article>> getArticles() async {
    var response = await http.get(articleUrl);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);

      articleList = ApiResult.fromJson(data).articles;

      return articleList;
    } else {
      print("Error");
    }
  }

}
```

Here is the Repository class :

```
class ArticleRepository {
  ArticleApiProvider articleApiProvider = ArticleApiProvider();

  Future<List<Article>> getTheArticles() {
    articleApiProvider.getArticles();
  }
}
```

In `main.dart` I am getting the json reponse by using `ArticleApiProvider` :

```
ArticleApiProvider articleApiProvider = ArticleApiProvider();
articleApiProvider.getArticles();
```

But if I use the `repository` class, I am getting null :

```
ArticleRepository aricleRepository = ArticleRepository();
aricleRepository.getTheArticles():
```

What's the wrong here?

Comment: You need to put a **return** before articleApiProvider.getArticles();

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I just got it.